# linked list print every nth integer method

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I need to write a method for a linked list class that:

Print the contents of every "nth" node in the list. Obtain the "n" from the user, ensure it is 
greater than 0.

How would i go about doing this?

```
 public void nthNode (int n) {
     if (n <= 0) {
        System.out.println("error");
     } else {
       //bla
     }
 }
```

Comment: I second the comment by @Marlon.  We'll give hints to move you in the right direction, but the whole point of homework is to learn, not to ask a bunch of strangers to do the work for you.

Comment: im thinking make a counter, and make a while loop saying while curr.next != null then iterate somehow through each node and if data mod n == 0, system.out.println the data of the node.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void nthNode (int n) {
     if (n <= 0) {
        System.out.println("error");
     } else {
         for (int i = 0; i < size(); i += n) {
             //LinkedList#get(i);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over every element in the list. If the index of the current item is evenly divisible by n then print the element. You can check for even divisibility by using the modulus operator (% in Java)

Answer (score 0):

You main motive is to print the data of nodes when the counter will be a multiple of n.

so instead of checking the mod on data, u need to do it on counter and have the mod check with n.

Iterating over the link list (using say curr pointer) using while loop. Check for condition curr.next!=null. initialize count to 0. While iterating count the number of nodes traversed till now. If the (count  == n), then print the node data and initialize count to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a node class of some sort:

```
public void nthNode( int n ){
     if( n <= 0 ){
            System.out.println( "error" );
      } else {
         Node e = new Node();
         e = head;

         int count = 0;

         while( e != null ){

              if( count == n ){
                  //do stuff
                  break;
              }

              e = e.next;
              cout++;
     }

}
```

Sorry kinda sloppy but that's the gist.